# JMeter - plotting logins as Active Users

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, active-users

In My JMeter scenario, 500 threads do 4000+ user logins.
The results captures only active threads vs response time. But, I would like to get number of users(logins) vs response time.

Is there a way to plot the successful Login transactions as users in JMeter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) chart what you're looking for?

[image: JMeter Plugins Transactions per Second]

You can install them as a part of `3 Basic Graphs` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Basic Graphs]

---

Alternative option is placing all the requests related to the "Login transaction" under the [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) and configure it to generate "Parent sample", this way the whole login sequence will be treated as a single request by any JMeter [listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) and/or chart.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T... But, those options are not providing the cumulative results in the graph...It gives the number of logins per second. So, I couldn't infer total number of logins happened so far at particular time...